# Laravel-PHP Fatal error: During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists($key)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to run php artisan serve command but i can't. I'm facing this error

`PHP Fatal error:  During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists($key)`

My php version is PHP 8.1.12 (cli).

And my composer.json file is

```
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "anhskohbo/no-captcha": "^3.2",
        "crocodicstudio/crudbooster": "^5.4",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
    },
```

I think I have to upgrade my Laravel project version.

please help me to figure out this problem and help me to resolve this.

I'll be very thankful to you.

Comment: *"I think I have to upgrade my Laravel project version"* - More than that. You're targeting PHP `^7.1`, but all of the PHP 7.x versions are [end of life](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php). You're also targeting Laravel `5.8`, which has been end of life since [Feb. 2020](https://laravelversions.com/en). If you have PHP 8.1, you can aim for anything Laravel 7.x+ (8.x, 9.x, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downgrade your php version. Composer "php": "^7.1.3", but you use PHP 8.1.12.
Or you can upgrade Laravel version
Check https://bytexd.com/fix-laravel-return-type-of-illuminatesupportcollectionoffsetexistskey/

Comment: *"Downgrade your php version."* - No, don't do that. PHP 7.x is [end of life](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php). The rest of your answer is fine (if a little vague), but suggesting that is just not a good idea.